# having simple buttons in papervision

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d

there's a simple thing in papervision I can't do , I want to have a simple button on my swf like we have in flash , just a 2d square which is on screen and you can click on it and have some action , I didn't find any solutions for this
I'll be appreciated if someone can help me with this
thanks

Comment: should be easy render the graphics into a Plane from a MovieClip or Bitmap. For interactivity, follow @Michiel's tips on the InteractiveScene3DEvent and also make sure the following have the _interactive_ property set to _true_: **viewport**,**displayobject3D**,**material**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would like to say that you'd better not use papervision anymore, since that project has been stopped and will not be developed any further. It is better to change to Away3D for that matter.

That being said, I do have the solution to your problem. It is actually very simple. You can just add an OBJECT_PRESS-eventListener to a 3Dobject, or you can create a button that isn't a 3Dobject and justr place it over your view (if you want a 2D-button).

```
//If you want a 3D-object to act as a button
yourButton.addEventListener(InteractiveScene3DEvent.OBJECT_PRESS, someFunction);

//If you want a 2D-non-papervision-button to be over your view.
var yourButton:Button = new Button();
stage.addChildAt(yourButton, IndexHigherThanYourView);
```

Comment: thanks , I tried to learn Away3D , cause everyone was saying the same . but seb-lee's video tutorial was a very good tutorial on papervision , and Away3D doesn't have such tutorials. thanks for the answer